# xtightvncviewer ConnectToTcpAddr: connect: Connection refused

Tags: docker

I'm running GUI in docker container on local box and use xtightvncviewer to display. In docker container, `ps aux` shows `Xvfb :2` and `x11vnc -forever` are running, xtightvncviewer localhost:2 with password throws error `ConnectToTcpAddr: connect: Connection refused`. What could be wrong?

Comment: Please provide more information. Commands you are running, compose file if used, Dockerfile, etc.

Comment: What port is it running as? Don't confuse X session `:2` with port number.